# How do I do a simple forwarding to multiple email addresses in Google Apps

Tags: email, forwarding, google-workspace

I have a seemingly very simple problem: I want all emails that are sent to invoice@[mydomain].com to be forwarded to three different addresses, which are not 
in the same domain. One of the recipients is a bot that processes incoming invoices and so there is no human to answer incoming messages.

I use Google Apps for email, and the only available method I have found is "groups". However, this is a method that is intended for groups of people to have discussions, which means that you can "invite" people, and only invited persons can post stuff. This is of course not at all what I want. Firstly, I don't want to approve stuff that comes in there, since I don't know who will send invoices to me. Secondly, the invoice processing bot cannot answer an invitation. What alternative methods are there?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'll have to add a default routing setting from the Admin console.

From your Admin console go to Apps > g suite > gmail > default routing.

Click Add Setting option and add 'invoice@[mydomain].com' in the recipient option.

Then scroll down and and select the 'Also deliver to' option and one-by-one add all the 3 IDs you want to receive the mails.

This way, all the mails received on 'invoice@[mydomain].com' will be forwarded